# How should I use extra summer squash?

Tags: storage-method, vegetables, culinary-uses, squash

My CSA delivers me a lot of summer squash, more than I can actually find the time to cook in a week. Can I freeze the remainder in some way? Is there a quick recipe I should be making that stores well? I'm not thinking primarily of meals here -- if I had the time to cook dinners more regularly I wouldn't be overwhelmed -- but of things I can store for a while.

Comment: find a recipe for zucchini bread, substitute squash, then freeze it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel your pain. If only I liked summer squash better...

You definitely can freeze squash -- thick slice it, blanch it in salty water briefly until almost tender, transfer to an ice bath until it's chilled, bag it, and put in the freezer.

Later, thaw and use with recipes that don't require ultra-crisp squash.

Answer (score 5):

I blanch it, run it under cold water or put into ice water to stop any further cooking.  Then I pat dry and store individual portions in the freezer.  I love to make fritters with them and this makes it easy to do, not to mention it is a great way to save the wonderful flavors of summer squash.

Hope this is helpful.

SORRY, I see somebody else already answered.  Still, now you know at least two of us agree that squash can be frozen.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have recipes that take shredded squash (or zucchini while you're at it), you can shred the squash and then place it in a freezer bag and then into the freezer.

This works really well for zucchini that's bound for bread, but squash for some soups, bread, or similar uses would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Squash/Pumpkin Ravioli?
The filling is very easy to make 
(Squash, egg, nutmeg, cinnamon, Cream)
and freezes very well.

Answer (score 1):

I slice it and cook 10 min in a little olive oil.  Sometimes I add peppers,onions,eggplant,or tomatoes. Freeze in bags and pop into recipes such as sauces,soups, or stews. The squash actually has a bit of crunch to it doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I just made refrigerator pickles out of a couple.   Treat it just like you do cucumbers.